# How to find the reason for Java Process not opening intended port?

Tags: java, port

Have a Java Process to which I am passing env variable SERVER_PORT=9043 and then starting the process. Process starts, and writes to the log file, and in the log file I can see the following line:

> c.e.r.a.j.CustomJettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory: Server initialized with port: 9043

But when I do netstat, I do not see this port open. No other process is also using this port. Starting the process with strace does not reveals much. If I cat the file /proc/PID/environ, I can see the SERVER_PORT variable defined and assigned the PORT number.

How can I find out more on what is happening and why is the process not able to open the port?

Comment: It sounds like  the problem is the with the non-Java process itself.

Comment: @SteveSmith Which non-java process?

Comment: The one (I'm assuming) you're starting with Process.start();

Comment: @SteveSmith Am using the following command on bash commandline: 

java -Dspring.profiles.active=modulename -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true -jar handler-1.0.0.jar --spring.config.location=app.yml